# Numerical integration for equations of motion

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, physics, astronomy

```
m = 10(*body of mass*)
e = 0.705(*eccentricity*)
MA = 354.4223(*Mean Anomoly*)
Mo = 12.30336608(*Mean Motion*)
n = Mo*(2*Pi/86400)
μ = 3.986004418*10^14(*Grav parameter of Earth*)
ψ = MA + 2*e*Sin[MA] + 1.25*e^2*Sin[2*MA](*True Anomoly*)
a = ((μ^(1/3))/(n^(2/3)))(*semi major axis*)
```

I have a body of mass `m` that is orbiting the Earth. `m` has an inital postion of 8.65e6e6 m, using the equation of orbital motion:

```
r[ψ] == a(1 - e^2)/(1 + e Cos[ψ])
```

and the initial velocity of 6681.5 m/s using equation of orbtial velocity

```
v = Sqrt[μ (2/r - 1/a)]
```

The body of mass has a gravitational force of:

```
Fg = -G M m/r^2 = μ m/r^2
```

(G M = μ, the standard gravitational parameter of earth)

where the acceleration of the body is given by

```
a = Fg/m = -μ/r^2
```

I'm trying to use `NDsolve` and the differetial equations

```
orb = 
  {x''[t] == (-μ x[t])/(x[t])^3, 
   y''[t] == (-μ x[t])/(x[t])^(3), 
   x[0] == 8.65*10^6, y[0] == 0, 
   x'[0] == 0, y'[0] == 6681.5};
```

I've been following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dEWTX2yA8qM

I'd like to use the expression `r`, to show elliptical motion of the body, over the range {ψ, 0, 2 Pi}.

I'm trying to plot the orbital path of the body `m`, using these differential equations. However im stuck at this point.

I think I'm on the right path to solving this problem, but I think I have to include the expression for `r[ψ]` in the differential equation. Any guidance on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193952/plotting-elliptical-orbits-using-verlet-method

Comment: No, you do not have to introduce an expression for r into the differential system described by orb; you only have to rewrite the Cartesian system described by orb in polar coordinates and solve ***that*** system.

Comment: Thanks m_goldberg, that makes sense. would the  differential equation of motion: x''[t]=Fg/x[t]^2 and the initial conditons that have been stated be enough to solve this?